# Silverlight bingMapContril using LocalproxyPage to downLoad MapTiles Extremely Slow

Tags: silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

as we know silverlight5 has ability to get pageElement's visual so we can print or save them as pictrue.but if your MapTilesSource uri is in a differentDomain to your silverlight Application host site,you can not get BingMapControl's visual,because of "cross-domain problem",clr would throw a System.Security.SecurityException.
To avoid this problem I add a Proxy aspx page in the silverlight host site,which can send bingMap TileImage request to the remote MapTilesService.
here is my customer Class inherit from TileSource:

```
public class GoogleTileSource : TileSource
        {
            public GoogleTileSource()
                : base("http://mt{0}.google.cn/vt/lyrs={1}@180000000&hl=zh-CN&gl=cn&z={2}&x={3}&y={4}")
            {
                this.Type = GoogleTileType.Hybrid;
            }

 public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
        {
            string TargetUrl = string.Format(this.UriFormat, this.Server, (char)this.Type, zoomLevel, x, y);
            return new Uri(string.Format(http://localhost:52879/MapTilesServerProxy.aspx + "?sourceUrl={0}", TargetUrl));
            //return new Uri(string.Format(this.UriFormat, this.Server, (char)this.Type, zoomLevel, x, y));
        }

 public int Server
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

 public GoogleTileType Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

here is my proxy page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MapTilesServerProxy.aspx.cs" Inherits="AeroZH.Web.MapTilesServerProxy" %>
<%@ Import Namespace=System.Net %>
<%@ Import Namespace=System.IO %>
<%@ Import Namespace=System.Diagnostics %>
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        ProxyRequest();
    }

    private void ProxyRequest()
    {
        try
        {
        string url = "";
        url = this.Page.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split(new string[] { "?sourceUrl=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
        Debug.WriteLine("url:" + url);

            Debug.WriteLine(url + "——requestTime:" + System.DateTime.Now);
            HttpWebRequest loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            loHttp.Timeout = 10000;     // 10 secs
            loHttp.UserAgent = "Web Client";
            HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loHttp.GetResponse();
            Debug.WriteLine(url + "——responseTime:" + System.DateTime.Now);
            using (Stream inputStream = loWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096 * 100];
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                } while (bytesRead != 0);
                Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                Response.End();

            }
            loWebResponse.Close();
            if (loHttp != null)
                loHttp.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

after this work，bingMapcontrol successfully make its image request thought the proxy page ,and the ProxyPage's request get response form remote server is also success.but only a few mapTiles show in the map.
  I using debug.write to trace response status,almost everyRequest has correct response,i don't know why only few mapTiles show in map.

Answer (score 0):

First off, using Google map tiles in Bing Maps is against the terms of use of both the Bing Maps and Google Maps terms of use.

Secondly, The Bing Maps Silverlight control is nearing end of life. The documentation is already offline and it won't be long before the control is disabled. No new development should be one with it. Also, the end of life for Silverlight in general was announced a few years ago.